# How to find most frequently used words to describe a category

Tags: python, countvectorizer

I have two columns. One is Animal and the other is their description. I want to find the most common words associated with each animal in Python. Also, I want to add in sets of words including english stop words and bi-grams and tri-grams.  Maybe find the top 20 words/phrases.

```
dataset = pd.read_sql( q , dlconn )
x=dataset['Animal']
y= dataset[Description]
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words = esw, ngram_range=(1, 3))
```

Comment: Can you give sample data? Would a particular animal be found in multiple rows or just one?

Comment: x: [dog, dog, cat, cat, cat, rabbit] , y:[woof hairy, hairy big, meow, meow meow 
    whiskers, carrot]

Answer (score 0):

To find most frequent words, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Animal': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'rabbit'] ,
    'Description':['woof hairy', 'hairy big', 'meow', 'meow', 'meow whiskers', 'carrot']
})

most_common = {}
for animal, grp_df in df.groupby('Animal')['Description']:
    counts = Counter([word for phrase in grp_df.tolist() for word in phrase.split(' ')])
    most_common[animal] = max(counts.keys(), key=lambda x: counts[x])
```

Output:

```
{'cat': 'meow', 'dog': 'hairy', 'rabbit': 'carrot'}
```

Comment: hi thanks for getting back to me! I appreciate the assist. Would you be able to show it using the code i have so far? how do you incorporate esw and trigrams?